# IE11 - How to enable scrollbar in disabled fieldset

Tags: html, css

Here there is a small example of my page. I need to disable all input fields but the scrollbar. This works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but not with IE.

```css
tbody{
  display:block;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<fieldset disabled>
   <table>
      <thead>
          <tr><th>test</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
          <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
          <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
          <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
          <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>  
</fieldset>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```css
tbody{
  display:block;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr> <td> <input type="text" disabled /> </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> <input type="text" disabled /> </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> <input type="text" disabled /> </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> <input type="text" disabled /> </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td> <input type="text" disabled /> </td> </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</fieldset>
```

Or using `pointer-events` (still, user can tab through the inputs, but that can be prevented with `tabindex="-1"`, but then again, why not just add `disabled`)

```css
fieldset tbody {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
fieldset tbody input {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
</fieldset>
```

Or use an extra div

```css
fieldset div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div>
    <table disabled>
      <tbody>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td> <input type="text" /> </td> </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
  </div>  
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the snippet I posted is a very simple example. In my project, columns are generated dynamically and more than one. If it's possible I'd prefer using the fieldset solution with any fix for IE.

Comment: @Luca I added a 2:nd sample, does that work for you?

Comment: The 2nd example changes the original behaviour and does not fits my needs.

Comment: @Luca Added 1 more sample using pointer events ... and as there is no good fix for IE, and as you add your column dynamically, why just not add the disabled to each column when add them in the first place? ... and if they are to be disabled, why use input's at all, why not style a span as an input?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate it. I've got a single page that shows its content in edit mode and read-only mode based on the role/permission that a certain user has when he logs in. Columns are generated dinamically by ng-repeat (angular) and also disable is managed by angular with ng-disabled. Probably the best solution is the first one you proposed me. Moving the disable (or ng-disabled) to each field seems the only way to acheive the aim.

Comment: @Luca For readability I would go with that (set disabled on the input themselves),  and as well being a more normal way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest wrapping the fieldset in an extra div and apply your styles there.
IE seems to disable the scrollbar functionality on disabled elements.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px; overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<fieldset disabled>
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
   <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
   <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
   <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
   <tr> <td> <input type="text"/> </td> </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>  
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't want to scroll the entire table. If I add an header I get a different behaviour with your and my code.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the feedback, what is different, and which header are you using?